Why is my inductor behaving like a capacitor?
I have an inductor coil (3 spools are connected in series) & I wish to find its inductance.
                                                       
I tried using a multimeter to measure the current slope when this coil is connected to a DC source, but the values halted after some time & the slope didn't feel very linear to me. That's when I decided to probe for the resistance of the coil, and found that out to be ~233 ohms. So I decided to figure out the RL time constant to know what the value is. I connected this coil to a known resistor (1k) & probed for voltage across the coil with a scope. I turned a DC power supply on & off to see the edges & find the \$\tau\$ of this circuit.
Here's the strange part - I expected the voltage curve to spike up to 5 at \$t=0^+\$, decrease in an exponential fashion to a value the resistors divider divides it to (i.e. \$\frac{233}{(1k+233)}\cdot5\$), and when I turn the Power Supply off, see the same kind of spike in the opposite direction before it discharges to 0. But instead, I'm seeing a curve that rises according to the shape of \$1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}\$, and then it discharges when I switch the Power Supply off.
                                                     
I'm not even sure if the time constant of the edges is even \$\frac{L}{R}\$ since the curve suggests that this might be a capacitor. Even if I do assume this to be the case, the TC of this suggests that the inductance of this coil is in the order of 20-30H, which seems like a lot for a coil of this size.
I tried simulating the circuit to ensure my intuition is correct, and the simulation agrees with me. Here's a quick sim on LTspice:

I also did a theoretical analysis to confirm what the behaviour would look like (Inductor would be an open circuit at \$t=0^+\$, voltage across inductor due to \$\frac{di}{dt}\$ would decrease over time till it reaches it's DC steady point of a voltage divider. Same rationale when change in current is opposite). I tried probing the coil for capacitance, but the capacitance meter couldn't register a value (you'd expect pFs at best, but I don't think it'll change the expected behaviour of the voltage across the inductor). I had a diode earlier for discharging but then I removed it after seeing this response to learn more. I probed for the resistance of the Power Supply, and it's 50 M\$\Omega\$ when it's turned ON & 1.1k\$\Omega\$ when turned OFF.
The curve I'm seeing would make sense if this was a capacitor instead of an inductor. I'm not sure whether the time constant of the output I'm seeing is \$\frac{L}{R}\$. Any ideas why this is the case?

What is the time constant of the power supply by itself?

I'm suspecting the impedance of the power supply.

It is convenient to measure the inductance, of which the resistance R is known, to use a sinusoidal signal generator with known peak amplitude with known frequency. Let k be the ratio between the measured voltage of the generator and that at the terminals of the inductor, then the inductance will be equal to: L = R/(omega sqrt(k^2-1))

To measure the inductance of an inductor, there are classical methods in electrical engineering, one is based on the Maxwell bridge, the other on the Anderson bridge. (You can find them online with examples I suppose)

The supply's power switch is not the way to implement this, since it's on the wrong side of its own output circuitry. That output no doubt consists of a capacitance right across it. Maybe the circuit you built looks more like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Naturally, the power supply output cannot rise instantly, since it has to charge C1, and the discharge curve won't be what you expect.
Try using your own switch, after the supply's output, and put the 1kΩ in a more appropriate place:

simulate this circuit
When switch SW2 is closed, L1 current will will rise to:
$$ I = \frac{V_{SUP}}{R_1} $$
Then, when you open SW2 again, the current through L1 will fall exponentially, with time constant:
$$ \tau = \frac{L_1}{R_1 + R_2} $$
All that current must flow via R2, so if you measure R2's voltage you will see it go from \$+V_{SUP}\$ to some negative value (depending on \$I\$), and decay to zero thereafter, with the same time constant \$\tau\$.
Do not omit R2 while probing with your 'scope. All that current will be pushed through the scope and damage it.

R1 is the coil resistance.

@greybeard Yes, but I assume OP knows that, since his own LTSpice circuit uses the same technique, a discrete resistor, to represent it.

@SimonFitch I suspected that as well, but I expected the capacitance meter to read some capacitance across the coil if that is the case. Based on the simulations I ran, the parallel parasitic capacitance across the coil would have to be >1uF if it has to change the shape of the curve, but it would also bring a slope in its steady states since the cap would discharge over time. The voltage levels I saw on the scope stay steady once I switch the power supply ON & OFF
